# Get days as float from an array of Timedelta and NaN

Tags: python, numpy, datetime, missing-data

I have a simple problem that causes me a lot of troubles: I have a a big 2D array which is a mixture of `datetime.Timedelta` objects and `np.nan`, simplified looking like this:

```
tdarray = np.array([dt.timedelta(days=5), np.nan])
```

Now I want to get the days and float/integer from the timedelta object, while leaving the `np.nan` as it is, i.e. the result should be `np.array([ 5., nan])`.

Getting the days from the timedelta object is easy with `.days`, and applying the function the array should work e.g. with `np.fromiter` and then reshaping. But how do I catch the error that occurs when trying to get the days from NaN? I tried masking, but this also fails with the AttributeError that the `MaskedArray` does not have the attribute `days`. Is there any simple solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of the fact that `np.nan` is the only object not equals to itself. Note that if your array contains other objects, they should have the equality operator defined, else this will throw an error.

```
tdarray = np.asarray([dt.timedelta(days=5), np.nan])
mask = tdarray == tdarray  # This gives array([True, False])
tdarray[mask] = [x.days for x in tdarray[mask]]
# Optionally cast to float
tdarray = tdarray.astype(np.float64)
```

Or you can simply rebuild the array

```
tdarray = np.asarray([x.days if x == x else x for x in tdarray],
                     dtype=np.float64)
```

And if `tdarray` is a ND array (N > 1) then

```
shape = tdarray.shape
tdarray = np.asarray([x.days if x == x else x 
                      for x in tdarray.ravel()],
                      dtype=np.float64).reshape(shape)
```

Comment: Thank you very much!
It was not asked, but maybe it is worth noting that the latter two methods don't work for me for 2D arrays, but the first one does!:-)

Comment: @user3017048 Your original question suggests that `tdarray` is 1D... Yes, the latter two breaks for 2D array because iterating over `tdarray` gives 1D arrays and we cannot apply `math.isnan` or do `x.days` on them. What you can do is use `tdarray.ravel()` to flatten the array before iterating over it then reshape `tdarray` to its original shape.

Comment: @user3017048 I have updated my answer for 2D case. Strange, I thought `math.isnan` also works on generic object, but I was wrong, so I removed that answer.